# Pandas Dataframe: removing duplicated rows with ignoring one specific column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| idx | A | B | C | modified date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2022-06-30 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2022-06-30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2022-06-30 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2022-07-10 |

I want to remove duplicated rows for Columns `A`/`B`/`C` but not `modified date`. If the duplicated rows have different values in `modified date`, keep the greater value in `modified date`.

The results should be like this:

| idx | A | B | C | modified date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2022-06-30 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2022-07-10 |

It drops the rows of index 0 and 1, because they have the same values with index 3, but their values in `modified date` are smaller.

**Note: There are about 30 columns for checking duplicated data in my real case. Also, there are two columns needs to be ignored when checking duplication in my real case. I just use the column `A`/`B`/`C`/`modified date` to simplify the question.**

Using `df.drop_duplicates()` is not enough.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on updated comments:

It sounds like you want the rows with the max `modified date` per group.

This can be done with `.groupby()` + `.idxmax()`:

```
data = {
   'idx': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3},
   'A': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1},
   'B': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2},
   'C': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 3},
   'modified date': {
      0: pd.Timestamp('2022-06-30 00:00:00'),
      1: pd.Timestamp('2022-06-30 00:00:00'),
      2: pd.Timestamp('2022-06-30 00:00:00'),
      3: pd.Timestamp('2022-07-10 00:00:00'),
   },
   'D': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1},
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['modified date'].idxmax()]
```

```
   idx  A  B  C modified date  D
3    3  1  2  3    2022-07-10  1
2    2  1  2  4    2022-06-30  2
```

---

It looks like you want to pass `subset=` and `keep=` (assuming the dates are sorted)

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B', 'C'], keep='last')
```

```
   idx  A  B  C modified date
2    2  1  2  4    2022-06-30
3    3  1  2  3    2022-07-10
```

Comment: The dates are NOT sorted, and in real data, I have 2 columns need to be ignored (The two independent columns are hard to be sorted). :(

Comment: @XareeLee Alrighty. Can you show a more realistic example?

Comment: What do you mean by "hard to be sorted"? you need to do that to choose which one you will keep anyway.

Comment: @XareeLee It sounds like you may be looking for the `.idxmax` per group based on the `modified date`. If you can clarify on this and/or provide a more realistic example, it will help the people trying to answer.

Comment: Is that possible to find the `idxmax` for two columns (e.g. `year` column and then `month` column)?

Comment: @XareeLee Well, they could have different indexes (be on different rows) - what should happen in that case?

Comment: If `year` is the same, then compare the `month` in the same group.

Comment: @XareeLee Not sure if there is an easy way to do that. Perhaps you can sort the data and do the drop duplicates instead: `df.sort_values(['year', 'month']).drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B', 'C'], keep='last')`

Comment: OK. thanks. I think this is ok.